# Should I use Windows deployment server to deploy Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, deployment

I've installed the Windows Deployment Server role on to Windows 2008 R2, I've found the Windows PE .wim file from the Windows 7 AIK and added it to my deployment server. On a client I can now do a network boot and have the Windows PE image load, now on my previous Windows 2003 Deployment Server I'd type WDSCapture and upload the Windows client to the server but WDSCapture is no longer present. Am I missing something? Should I be using Windows Deployment Server for Windows 7?

Many thanks
Scott

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the Windows Automated Installation Kit for Win 7, which will give you ImageX, which used in conjunction with WDS will give you all the tools you need.

Comment: Thanks, do I install Windows 7 AIK on the WDS server?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Deployment Toolkit is what you're looking for: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx